# jQuery modifies string that's partial html

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing

I have a problem with replacing links of a string with jQuery. If I pass the string to jQuery, using

```
$("<div />").html(myContentString))
```

jQuery strips out all non-closed html tags. If I have an unopened ul-element, and only have the closing  in the string, jQuery strips that away.

Any idea on how to iterate over all href attributes of a "partial html string"? I made a quick example which will illustrate this better:

http://jsfiddle.net/yporqgod/

```
var content = "<li>Option <a href='jadda1'>number 1</a></li><li>Option number <a href='2'>dos</a></li></ul></div>",
    $content = $('<div/>').html(content);

console.log($content.html()); /* no </ul> nor </div> */

$content.find("a").each(function() {
    var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', 'exchanged-' + thisHref); 
});

console.log($content.html());`
```

Thanks in advance.

DS.
The reason for having non-closed html tags in a string is that I have to split a bigger chunk of html into three pieces. Don't ask, that's a completely other story ;)

Comment: Then you should concatenate those 3 strings before appending them. This is not done by jQuery, it's browser that removes those closing/invalid tags. This smells like as a XY problem.

Comment: I cannot do that. I need to treat all three strings separately. Any idea on finding all a-tags in a string, grab their href attribute and the inner html inside the a-tag instead then?

Comment: You `find` method selects the `a` elements without any problem based on the current markup. Is iteration a problem or invalid markup?

Comment: Markup is. Or was. It was as easy as replacing some stuff. Crap. Sorry for bothering you. Solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yporqgod/3/

Answer (score 0):

That's just how DOM and jQuery work. The best solution i can give you is to manually add them back when you're done:

```
console.log($content.html() + '</ul></div>');
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. `</ul></div>` is not a valid representation of HTML elements, concatenating it with the _parsed_ html content doesn't make lot of sense.

Comment: @Vohuman As i understand it, the OP then wants to concatenate this with other HTML strings, and it'll all end up working.

Comment: I, or the script, don't know what to append, could be really anything, this was just an example.